# Remove blank line from Spool file

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

I am creating a .tab file using `Spool` simply by doing a select statement.

The select statement returns Y

However when running the below script the output files has a blank line after the Y.

Can you please assist me in removing the line as I have tried looking all over.

```
Set Heading Off;
SET NEWPAGE NONE;
SET LINESIZE 1;
SET PAGESIZE 0;
SET TRIMSPOOL ON;
SET SQLBLANKLINES OFF;
SET FEEDBACK off;
SET WRAP on;
SPOOL \\Planning\Lists\Admin\elapse.tab;
Select txt1 from ack_work_text_1;
Spool Off;
```

Comment: @Firstly why did you need a `commit` at the end? Secondly, what's the content of `ack_work_text_1`?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan  the commit is there for a procedure i executed(forgot to take it out) contents for ack_work_text_1 - only has two columns 1 seq number 2 indicator - which is a char type

Comment: Thanks Dylan.  I'm having trouble reproducing this (using SQLPlus: Release 12.2.0.1.0).  Files with no empty lines are produced.  There are drawbacks to using a mismatched version of sqlplus with your database, but maybe its worth a try to test out a newer version of sql*plus and see how it fares for you?